# sometimes I see/comment/answer newest questions which then disappear from the list

Tags: discussion

I don't know if this really "happens", or there is something I don't know about the questions workflow, but I just answered to a question, and another answer came too (none accepted), but then in the "unanswered => newest" list it disappears...

[image]

and it's not "closed" or "deleted": through my profile page I can still visit the question... and I just reloaded both pages... still the same.

is it some form of caching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the question disappeared from the **Unanswered list**.

The [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/72128/2217) is very much still visible. (Right now it is still on the first [Newest Questions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest) page.)

Only questions with 0 up voted answers, and do not have an accepted answer appear on the unanswered list.

You answered it, and you answer has one up vote. That alone makes the question answered, but it has two up voted answered.
So the question *is*  definitely answered, and that is why it no longer shows up on the unanswered list.

Comment: oh yes, I thought only about accepted answers counted... thanks, I was puzzled...